# how do i raise an exception when i prompt user to enter a number

Tags: python, exception

i want to get input from user to fill the empty list. if user enters a negative integer- it will not get appended rather a ValueError will be raised.

```
nameList = []
count = 0 
try:
    while count < 5:
        num = int(input('Enter a number: '))
        if num < 0:
            except NameError:
                print('Positive integers only!')
        numList.append(num)
        count = count + 1
        

print(numList)
```

I tried adding assertion after the try and before the while but I got syntax error since num is not defined.

Comment: If you want to raise an exception, use `raise SomeException('message')`.

Comment: `except` needs to be at the same indentation level as `try`. But none of the code you posted will raise a `NameError`.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any reason to raise an exception here. If the input is less than zero, just use `continue` to go back to the start of the loop body immediately.

Comment: @chepner hello, thank you for responding! i'm trying to get comfortable with using exceptions since i am currently learning it. so i try to implement it as much as possible

Comment: You should get used to using them *properly*; don't try to fit them in where they aren't necessarily required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's little point to raising an exception that you intend to immediately catch. Just use `continue` to go back to the top of the loop body.

```
nameList = []
count = 0 
while count < 5:
    try:
        num = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    except ValueError:
        print("Not an integer")
        continue
    if num < 0:
        print('Positive integers only!')
        continue

    numList.append(num)
    count = count + 1
```

While you are at it, use a `for` loop to repeat the body (successfully) 5 times, without the need to explicitly increment `count`:

```
for _ in range(5):  # _ instead of count to emphasize that you don't use the variable
    try:
        num = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    except ValueError:
        print("Not an integer")
        continue
    if num < 0:
        print('Positive integers only!')
        continue

    numList.append(num)
```

---

I should soften this a little. *If* you intend to handle an exception raised by `int` and your own explicit exception in exactly the same way, I wouldn't say "no" to using `raise ValueError("Not an integer")` in the `try` block. But, this is an opportunity to provide a different error message for non-integers and negative integers, so I would still recommend separating the two checks as above.

Answer (score 1):

Use `raise` to raise an exception:

```
        num = int(input('Enter a number: '))
        if num < 0:
            raise ValueError('Positive integers only!')
```

Use `except` to handle an exception raised in the corresponding `try` (that is, the `except` and `try` need to be at the same indentation level).  If you wanted to handle the ValueError by printing an error message and continuing the loop, you might do:

```
    try:
        num = int(input('Enter a number: '))
        if num < 0:
            raise ValueError('Positive integers only!')
    except ValueError as e:
        # This will happen if the user entered something
        # non-numeric OR a valid but negative number.
        print(e)
        continue
```

Answer (score 1):

```
numList = []
count = 0 
while count < 5:
    try:
        num = int(input('Enter a number: '))
        if num < 0:
            raise ValueError('Positive integers only!')
        numList.append(num)
        count += 1
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
        
print(numList)
```